# Aerial Imagery Capture Location

Tags: imagery, .sup

I have been tasked with finding out where an airplane was when it took the photo used in some aerial imagery that we have. I have been supplied with 'RAW' data and need to know how to interpret it towards determining the photo location for each image.

Here is what I have in file folders:

1. %image_name%_WM2.ads
2. %image_name%_WM2.hist
3. %image_name%_WM2.odf
4. %image_name%_WM2.odf.adj
5. %image_name%_WM2.prj
6. %image_name%_WM2.sup
7. %image_name%_WM2_x_x.tif

where x_x are a number of TIF files under the same base image name (e.g. 0_0 or 0_4 or 0_99).

There is a lot of data inside the SUP file that I feel is useful, but I don't know how to interpret it into my needs, if indeed it can be.

There is a lot of other information just outside this file structure within a file folder called CAM which contains a lot of files apparently to do with the sensors. I'm not sure if this data is useful in my current problem, but I have it if it helps.

With supposedly 'RAW' imagery data files, how can I extract out where each image was taken in space (X,Y,Z)?

Is there another way of determining photo location? What files should I request from the provider?